# How to code in c# programmatically (not using xaml)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I am working on silverlight and i am beginner. I know the question is very basic but as I am beginner I need help in achieving this. Yet I have written xaml code to create GUI but now I have to create GUI using c# and my problem is :

I know how to create a GUI but i dont know how to render it.

Like i know how to create a slider. I done it like this:

```
void createGrid()
        {
            Grid childGrid = new Grid();
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
            childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);


            Slider sl = new Slider();
            Grid.SetColumn(sl, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(sl, 0);
            childGrid.Children.Add(sl);

        }
```

But the problem is how to render it. I mean i just created project named "`NoMoreLife`" and after i created this function `CreateGrid()` and called it from constructor like this:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createGrid();
        }
```

My MainPage class is: (which contains the code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NoMoreLife
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            createGrid();
        }
        void createGrid()
        {
            Grid childGrid = new Grid();
            ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
            childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
            childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);


            Slider sl = new Slider();
            Grid.SetColumn(sl, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(sl, 0);
            childGrid.Children.Add(sl);

        }
    }
}
```

and MainPage.xaml is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NoMoreLife.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**How should I render this slider create which i have created using c#?** Because currently when I run the program I see nothing (no slider).

EDIT: After Dan's comment:

I have added check.cs class in my project now this class contains the code:

```
namespace NoMoreLife
    {
        public static class check
        {
            public static void createGrid()
            {
                Grid childGrid = new Grid();
                ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
                RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
                childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
                childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
                childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);
                childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowdef);

                Slider sl = new Slider();
                Grid.SetColumn(sl, 1);
                Grid.SetRow(sl, 1);
                childGrid.Children.Add(sl);
               // LayoutRoot.Children.Add(childGrid);
                this.Content = childGrid;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my call to the function is:

```
namespace NoMoreLife
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            check.createGrid();           
        }        
    }
}
```

here this.Content = childGrid; gives error.

**Note: Please note that I have to code in c# only not in xaml.**

Comment: Who is "they?" Because coding your UI in this way is ridiculous, except possibly as an academic exercise...

Comment: there is no thay actually it is because of bold letters i have written they.

Comment: LayoutRoot.Children.Add(childGrid); would add the chidlGrid you prgramatically created to the existing Grid on the page.

Comment: Alternatively, if you intend to replace the default Grid on the usercontrol (now called "LayoutRoot) you could remove that grid from the XAML and put this.Content = childGrid; in your code.

Comment: @user234839: so, why do you have to code in C# only? This is an inefficient and inflexible way to build a WPF GUI...

Comment: @DanPuzey just for experience in coding.

Comment: @user234839: If you want to practise coding, I'd recommend that you practise on something meaningful and sensible. You wouldn't try to build furniture out of sponge cake for experience in cooking! And by that, I mean: this is unlikely to be a valuable experience.

Comment: For the (few) legitimate cases where you need to build your UI in code behind, there is also XamlReader.Load

Comment: Totally agree with @danpuzey - if you want to experience coding in WPF then creating a GUI in C# is not a good experience. Try instead to set up a view and a view model, play around with binding and observable collections, using the `NotificationObject` class, learn LINQ. These are all much more relevant experiences to have with WPF.

Comment: @Mashton thanks for the suggestion but this problem is solved already. I am stuck somewhere here on a new problem . I SAY YOU THANKyou so much  IF YOU ARE ABLE TO HELP ME HERE / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956466/c-sharp-how-to-maintain-the-ticks-exactly-below-and-equal-to-the-coustomed-slide?noredirect=1#comment36905674_23956466

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `Grid` in code, but you're not doing anything with it. Typically, you might want to include that grid as the content of your form. Try adding this line at the bottom of your `createGrid` method:

```
this.Content = childGrid;
```

**EDIT** (in response to the updated code in the question):

Since your code is in a separate class to the window, you probably want to do this instead:

1. Change your method `createGrid` from a `void` to  instead return `childGrid`
2. Use the result of the method in your page's constructor:

`public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.Content = check.createGrid();
     }`

Comment: yes it worked. I wil mark it as answer soon because i am not able mark within 10 minutes.

Comment: thanks for the answer what if i have another class (Instead of MainPage) then i how will i render the UI ? because "Content" and "LayoutRoot" are not present there if  i try to add this code then it gives error that they are unknown and i am missing some reference or assembly .

Comment: thanks for the answer what if i have another class (Instead of MainPage) then i how will i render the UI ? because "Content" and "LayoutRoot" are not present there if i try to add this code then it gives error that they are unknown and i am missing some reference or assembly

Comment: You would need to share what code you actually have; the answer given matches the code you've shared so far. If you're trying to build UI from outside of a window or control then it's not going to be so easy (you need to return or pass your grid from this code to the UI container). Really, this is a horrible way to create a UI - I would expect that there's an easier way to solve whatever your problem is using Xaml and templating.

Comment: I have just edited the code for you. Th eproblem is i have such kind of situaion in the already existing project so no more options